# Wait for request to finish with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, request, setinterval

Consider the code below. This code sets an interval of 5 seconds before making another request to load the new values into part of a document.

The problem is that when a request takes a long time to resolve (>5 seconds) the requests will pile up. How can we make sure the new request will only be made when the request has finished?

In my internet search trying to answer this question, I have not come across this specific situation including `setInterval`. I came across a couple of suggestions using `async` or `promises`, but I have yet to discover how those could be implemented in this situation. Please forgive my inexperience in the topic.

```
    window.onload = () => {
        setInterval(refresh, 5000);
    }

    function refresh() {
        let myVariable = document.getElementById("myId").value;

        // reload part of the page for the new values
        $("#partial-id").load("partial.html", {
            myparameter: myVariable ,
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function again in the `.load()` callback function.

```
function refresh() {
    let myVariable = $("#myId").val();
    $("#partial-id").load("partial.html", {
        myparameter: myvariable
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
    });
}
```

This will repeat the function 5 seconds after the previous one completed.

Comment: Thank you! So the key take away for me is that the third argument of the `.load` function needs to be situated in an anonymous function in order for it to work. I do not understand why, but it is the correct solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be anonymous, but it has to be a function, not a function call.

Answer (score -1):

If the task performed gets wrapped into a promise, one can await it in an infinite loop:

```
 function refresh() {
    let myVariable = document.getElementById("myId").value;

   return new Promise(res => {
     // reload part of the page for the new values
     $("#partial-id").load("partial.html", {
        myparameter: myVariable ,
     }, res);
   });
}

(async function () {
    while(true) {
      await refresh();
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000));
   }
})();
```